# Regular Expression Lookbehind and Lookahead numerical test

Tags: regex

I am attempting to configure a regular expression that matches anything numerical value but 1211 so it will still match variations such as 1212 121 1122, 3411, etc

I am unable to test the below at http://regexpal.com/ as it does not seem to support ?

```
(1(?!2)|1(?!2)|(?<!1)2|(?<!2)1|[^1211])+|[0-9]{1,4})
```

Am I doing it right and also where can I test it?

**EDIT**

Please note that I need to implement in a rewrite module/filter.

Comment: Why don't you just do a negative match/comparison against the string `"1211"`? Also the character class `[^1211]` is the same as `[^12]`.

Comment: @BoltClock - That won't work as it also restricts variations such as 12, 121, 1121, etc

Comment: Yes, and I'm saying that `[^1211]` functions exactly the same as `[^12]` in that it restricts any number with just 1s and 2s.

Comment: @BoltClock - I need to only restrict the number 1211 but not 12, 11, 121, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify that regex a lot:

```
^(?!1211)[1-9]\d{0,3}$
```

As for `regexpal`, it's not working because your regex is invalid. You can tell right away because it as one more closing parenthesis than opening.

Comment: @PaulPRO - Beautiful is all I can say. It works like a charm. I am new to the world of lookaheads and lookbehinds so would you mind explaining how your answer is different to what I was doing as well as what \d means?

Comment: @Amber - When you say digits what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @jswolf19: It doesn't matter because he's only looking for at most 4 digits.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey I edited my post because it looks like you're searching for numerical values that are between 1 and 4 digits long. For the explanation: `^(?!1211)` says that the string can't begin with 1211, then everything after that `[1-9]\d{0,3}` is a normal expression which says one digit (first digit can't be 0) followed by up to 3 more digits and $ signifies the end of the string.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey If this is part of a url in a mod-rewrite you may want to omit the `^` and the `$` and replace them with what you expect before this number and after it in the url

Comment: @PaulPRO - Thanks. I don't quite follow the use of `(?!1211)`. Isn't `?!` a negative lookahead i.e. any value ahead of it or have I completely misunderstood it? Also I thought that if a string can't start with a particular character it would need to have `^` prefixed ahead of it e.g. `[^1211]`

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Anything is square brackets is part of a character class. [12] matches either a 1 or a 2, but not both. [a-z] matches any lowercase letter (but only one). you can negate a character class with the `^` so [^12] matches a single character that is anything other than a 1 or a 2. A look ahead acts just like a separate regular expression that continues from where you left off, but returns back to the same place in the string as it was when it finished. (?=1211) is the lookahead to say "The next 4 characters are 1211" To negate that you change it to (?!1211)

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey [^1211] is the same as [^12] because a character class is just a list of characters to match

Comment: @PaulPRO - Thanks. I got the part about [12] being character classes however am lost on how a lookahead and lookbehind works. For example how is (?=1211) a look ahead when the next characters are 1211?

Comment: @PaulPRO - I also meant to write (^1211) and not [^1211]. Just noticed the mistake.

Comment: @PaulPRO let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1790/discussion-between-peanutsmonkey-and-paulpro)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a simple route:

```
if (data != "1211"){
  // your other regex here
}
```

you can test it using javascript, if you are familiar with it.

Comment: I need to specify it in a rewrite module and hence cannot use any progamming language.